# JSF Browse button - radio button check

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf

I am using tomahawk library for browse button in my project.

Browse button code.

```
<td><t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{sampleService.file}" 
            valueChangeListener="#{sampleService.file}" /></td>
```

Radio Button Code

```
<td><input type="radio" /> This is compulsory</td>
```

I want to put a validation here,If the user has not checked the radio button, 
it should display a message to check radio button.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the radio button a fixed `id` and check its `checked` state in the `onclick` of the file field and if it's `false`, then display a message (alert?) and return `false` to block the browse button.

E.g.

```
<t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{sampleService.file}" valueChangeListener="#{sampleService.file}" 
    onclick="if (!document.getElementById('compulsory').checked) { alert('Please check radio button'); return false; }"
/>
<input type="radio" id="compulsory" /> This is compulsory
```

You could also wrap it in a JS function:

```
function checkCompulsory() {
    if (!document.getElementById('compulsory').checked) {
        alert('Please check radio button'); 
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

with

```
<t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{sampleService.file}" valueChangeListener="#{sampleService.file}" 
    onclick="return checkCompulsory()"
/>
<input type="radio" id="compulsory" /> This is compulsory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search here you will find it but for your intrest

```
    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var value;
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].type === 'radio'){
           if(radios[i].checked) {
            // get value, set checked flag or do whatever you need to
            value = radios[i].value;       
        } else {
              alert('This is compulsory')
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: How do i call this function when browse button is clicked

Comment: you have to check from here which will suit you the best.http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_inputFileUpload.html Usually 'onclick' would work